# Trigger native view events from Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created a HybridWebView according to https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview/ and created a native ios WKWebView. Now I want to add custom controls to go Back/Forward/Home in Forms but I am not sure what is the recommended way to make a call from my Xamarin forms view into my native view to for example trigger the GoBack() of the ios WKWebView browser?

Should I try to call into my native implementation or should the native view listen to events from the forms view?

Comment: You would probably need to use the [Xamarin MessagingCenter](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/) functionalities. It follows the publish-subscribe pattern. What you can do is publish a message in your Xamarin PCL and from your native projects you will have to subscribe to these published messages that comes from a Xamarin PCL trigger/event.

Comment: Finally got around to testing this and it works great, post your comment as an answer @ADimaano and I'll mark it as selected answer.

Comment: @Mårten where exactly did you put your subscibe and how did you get an instance of the WKWebView to execute the GoBack method?  Thanks!

Comment: @MarkErickson in my ios project in my HybirdWebViewRenderer constructor i have placed my subscriptions


`public HybridWebViewRenderer()
        {
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<HybridWebView>(this, MessageTypes.BrowserBackButtonClick.ToString(), GoBack);           
        }`


And my methods look like this:


`private void GoBack(HybridWebView sender)
        {
            if (Control.CanGoBack)
                Control.GoBack();
        }`

...sorry for the code formatting here, can't seem to get these snippets to look nice.

Comment: Perfect, I forgot about the Control in the ViewRenderer, that's where I couldn't figure out how to get the instance.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use the [Xamarin MessagingCenter](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/) functionalities. It follows the publish-subscribe pattern. What you can do is publish a message in your Xamarin PCL and from your native projects you will have to subscribe to these published messages that comes from a Xamarin PCL trigger/event.

Sample code:

In your PCL you will have something like this:

```
 MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage> (this, "Hi", (sender) => {
     // do something whenever the "Hi" message is sent
 });
```

And in your native project something like this:

```
 MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage> (this, "Hi");
```